# JavaScript - Read online text file from linux server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I am running a python HTTP Server on a Raspberry Pi (linux). I have a text file of coordinates, and when I press a button on my index page, I want to plot these coordinates on a map.

The problem I am having is reading in the file to my javascript function (the one that is being called by my button)

It goes something like this:

I press a button on http://www.mywebsite.com, which then I want to load the values from http://www.mywebsite.com/textFile.txt

Here is the closest I have come to getting something to work:

```
var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var sURL = "http://"
         + self.location.hostname
         + "/faq/requested_file.htm";

oRequest.open("GET",sURL,false);
oRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",navigator.userAgent);
oRequest.send(null)

if (oRequest.status==200) alert(oRequest.responseText);
else alert("Error executing XMLHttpRequest call!");
```

It seems to error in the oRequest.send(null) - and I have tried it with a ; after it as well. It was on a website without it though.

I know there are A LOT of similar questions on SO already, but I have looked through like 15 and all of the ones I have seen say use AJAX, which I don't think I can do since I am on linux? Or are trying to read a local file, which I don't think I am trying to do either.

I currently am not using jQuery in anything, but I think its pretty easy to just copy the file to my server isn't?

Comment: an XMLHttpRequest is AJAX: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I am not using jQuery at all now, but if all it takes to get this working is adding the jQuery file to my server, I am all for a solution in jQuery

Comment: And oh, cfs, definitely didn't know that. Is that most likely my problem then?

Comment: @adeneo the goto answer should not be 'use jQuery' especially when the OP is showing little understanding of the code at hand. Adding abstraction layers here just for ajax is not necessary.

Comment: @Shaun314 This probably isn't your problem, but you cannot manually set `User-Agent` header (see step 5 of the [`setRequestHeader` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method)). Can you correctly access the resource by typing the value of `sURL` into your browser's address bar?

Comment: I am assuming by "access the resource" you mean can I view the text file if I type in the URL and the answer is yes I can, and thanks for the info about user agent

Comment: @Shaun314 JFUI - you can skip domain/protocol part in sURL definition,  just `"/faq/requested_file.htm"` is enough; to help you out, you should listen for `readystatechange` event, instead of trying to use `oRequest.responseText` variable just after you send request, read about  asynchronous scripting in js. **[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** more info

Comment: hm, but you used sync request... check the console than